# ¿Cómo puedo evaluar si un string existe en un archivo con Perl?

Tags: string, archivo, perl

Estoy intentando verificar si un string existe dado un archivo.  El script que tengo no funciona y es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

print "Ejecutando script...\n\n";

@files = <prots/*>;

foreach $file (@files) {
    open(E,"<humano_3944_G.csv");
    @raw_data=<E>;
    close(E);
    $aux="";
   foreach $line (@raw_data)
   {
       chomp($line);
       if (grep {/<$line>/} $file)
       {
           $aux="y";
       }
    }
    if($aux eq "y")
    {
        print $file."\n";
    }       
}   
print "Hecho\n";
```

Comment: ¿Y qué falla? No nos pidas que debuggemos tu código :P

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunas líneas que te sobran porque estás mirando por archivos que luego no estás abriendo. Siempre abres uno con el nombre "humano_3944_G.csv".

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

print "Ejecutando script\n\n";

my $archivo = "humano_3944_G.csv";
my $string  = "ACTTCTA";

my $aux = "no";

open my $E, '<', $archivo or die "ERROR: no puedo abrir [$archivo]: $!\n";

while (my $line = <$E>) {
    if (-1 == index $line, $string) {   # index() busca $string dentro de $line
                                      # devuelve -1 si lo encuentra
        $aux = "sí";
        last;                         # no hace falta seguir buscando
    }
}                                     # $aux vale sí o no

close $E;

print "[$string] $aux está en [$archivo]\n";x

print "Hecho\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es más breve y optimo hacer lo siguiente, al menos así lo trabajo yo:

```
open(E,"$nombre_del_archivo");
while(<E>){
    $_=~s/\n//g;
    $_=~s/\r//g;
    # Esta linea compara que cada linea coincida 
    # con el patrón(REGEX) después del =~, en este caso que si la linea
    # contenga la palabra linea
    if($_ =~ /linea/){
            $valida=1;
    }
}
print "$valida\n";
```

Inclusive le puedes poner un last; dentro del if si el objetivo es solo encontrar la linea.
Espero sirva de referencia.

Comment: Con perl, lo breve no es necesariamente dos veces bueno :). Si tu código es más breve es porque tiene menos prints y porque no utilizas ciertas buenas prácticas que sí que usa @joaquín-ferrero

Comment: Efectivamente me ha gustado el code de Joaquín. Me sirve de referencia para mis scripts.